# Запрет слова в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение, допустим `^[a-zA-Z]{1,}$`. Оно разрешает все латинские буквы в любом количестве больше нуля. Но есть слово, допустим `test`, которое оно должно запретить несмотря на то, что все его символы разрешены. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: А вариант использования двух проверок вы не рассматривали?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240365/1688077):

`^(?!.*test)[a-zA-Z]+$`

Разрешает любое количество латинских букв, большее либо равное 1, но запрещает строки, в которых есть вхождение "test" на любой позиции.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно воспользоваться негативной опережающей проверкой (?!...)

```
  ^/(?!test)([a-zA-Z]{1,})$
```

Comment: Ваш вариант запрещает "testfoo", но разрешает "footestfoo".